# File size limit when uploading to Custom Translator

Tags: microsoft-translator

I'm having problems uploading an approx. 70 MB tmx file for training data. Could this be a file size problem? Is there a file size limit? 
The error I'm getting is not very descriptive:
Error
Sorry, operation failed. Error details:
 {
  "isTrusted": true
}

Comment: The error itself is called a script error. I think this is more of a problem on the app side, not on yours. Nevertheless, could you try uploading a smaller file and see what do you get?

Answer (score 1):

I had more success after individually compressing (zip'ing) my TMX files.

Comment: When I read the documentation, I saw there was a 50 MB file size limit. Despite that, I was able to upload some tmx files of about 60 MB. However, when I actually trained the system only 1 of the 9 tmx files I uploaded was actually used in the training. The alignment of the files looks OK, so not sure at this point why these segments were rejected.
I did try zipping some TMX files, but could not successfully upload those files. In the documentation, I believe I read that zipped files can only contain .align or .txt files. Maybe that's not actually the case, however.

Answer (score 1):

The upload size limit is set at **100 MB**, so that file should not have been a problem.  The script error you mentioned, `{"isTrusted" : true}`, is usually seen if your authentication token has expired.  Refreshing your browser should reload a new token.

Comment: Can you tell me where you saw the 100 MB limit specified?

Comment: The 100 MB limit is not currently stated but will be on the upload form in the next build.  I am a member of the MS Translator team and can confirm that this limit exists.

Comment: @ScottG And what should we do if the file is larger than that (even when zipped)?